# Default validation message ASP.NET Core

Tags: validation, asp.net-core

I created custom password validator to check the entering password by using my own regular expression. But when I testing it, the default error message is displayed first, and then mine. And I don’t understand how to remove this default message, so that only mine remains. My message is "Your password is incorrect".

Error message:
[image: Default message with mine]

And there is a code:

Validator:

```
    {

        public Task<IdentityResult> ValidateAsync(UserManager<User> manager, User user, string password)
        {
            List<IdentityError> errors = new List<IdentityError>();

            string pattern = "^(?=^.{12,}$)(?=.*[0-9]+)(?=.*[A-Z]+)(?=.*[a-z]+)(?=.*[&@^$%]+).*$";

            if (!Regex.IsMatch(password, pattern))
            {
                return Task.FromResult(IdentityResult.Failed(new IdentityError
                {
                    Code = "IncPass",
                    Description = "Your password is incorrect"
                })) ;
            }
            return Task.FromResult(IdentityResult.Success);
        }
    }
```

Controller methods

```
 [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Register()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                User user = new User { Email = model.Email, UserName = model.Email, Year = model.Year };
                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
                    }
                }
            }
            return View(model);
        }
```

Startup

```
  services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
                .AddPasswordValidator<CustomPasswordValidator>();
```

Comment: Please be more specific when stating your problem. What is it that you want to accomplish and what is the problem you are facing. Please edit your post for clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As soon as you call `AddIdentity` the default password validator is registered, even when you provide a additional password validator.

You need to register your password validator before calling `AddIdentity` like so:

```cs
services.TryAddScoped<IPasswordValidator<User>, CustomPasswordValidator>();
services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

As you can see, you then don't need the `AddPasswordValidator` call anymore.

Comment: Although this makes some sense, it makes me wonder what the point of the AddPasswordValidator<T>() method is.

Comment: The source code for the extension method does something very similar https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/IdentityBuilder.cs#L95

Answer (score 0):

The default `PasswordValidator` depends on a class called `IdentityErrorDescriber`.

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/PasswordValidator.cs

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.identityerrordescriber?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Although it looks possible to override the implementation, it seems this is intended for localization and might be difficult to achieve what you intend.